# After global IP reset can't access my website over domain, but works over ip

Tags: dns, connection, ip, webserver, reset

So recently I setup a webserver on windows 10 at my place (Frontend Angular 2). I setup all the necessary stuff like DNS, Hostfile, Firewall... Then I bought a domain and added my global ip to that domain. Everything worked fine until today, where my place had a power failure.

So I restarded the server and the router and noticed that I have a new global IP. So I changed the IP at the frontend and the backend and updated the IP at my domain name provider.

Now my problem is, that the domain isn't connecting to my webserver anymore - its timing out. But when I enter my global IP everything is working fine.

Any advices what I might have forgotten?

Comment: Try `nslookup yourdomain.com`. Does it print your new ip?

Comment: @AliMomenSani Yes it does!

Comment: @AliMomenSani Sorry for my previous answer, but when I do nslookup from an external network I get the old IP! When I do it from the webservers network I get the new IP.

Comment: So, you have to wait. Try `nslookup yourdomain.com dnsprovider.server` to check if the original dns server has the updated ip.

Comment: Also it's better to ask such question in [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: @AliMomenSani Thank you for your replies and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that from the network where I'm accessing the domain it must have been some kind of domain caching. Because the domain is accessible for people that are not on the same network as I am. So it actually works, just not for me in my particular network.